# How to get creation date of SharePoint site collections and Subsites using PnP-PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am getting the list of Site Collections with

```
$SiteCollections = Get-PnPTenantSite
```

However, the objects inside **$SiteCollections** won't have the "Created" property.

Likewise, I am getting the sub sites with

```
$subwebs=Get-PNPSubWebs
```

Here, I find the same issue, the objects inside **$subwebs** won't have the "Created" property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property is binding with web.

For example:

```
Connect-PNPOnline -Url https://domain.sharepoint.com/sites/Developer
$web=Get-PnPWeb -Includes Created
write-host $web.Created

$subweb=Get-PnPWeb -Identity "Team" -Includes Created
write-host $subweb.Created
```

Comment: Excellent. I have accepted your answer. One additional question, how can I find what properties are included in what cmdlets?